# How to get MAC or IP Addresses of devices connected to a switch using SNMP?

Tags: snmp

Using SNMP, how do I get the MAC address of the device connected to each port on the switch?  We're using HP ProCurve Switches.

I tried using the OID dot1dTpFdbPort but that seems to be giving me the MAC address of every device that's in communication with the switch, not just connected to it.

I'm trying to find the OID that will give me ports 1-48 in a list, and for each port, the MAC (or IP address) of the device connected to that port.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Thank you so much raz3r for your answer.
It works like a charm !

From your linux server :

> $ snmpwalk -v 1 -c public xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2 | grep
>   "INTEGER: 11"

(port number 11)

Will return :

> SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.44.118.138.64.143.95 = INTEGER: 11
>   SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.56.170.60.108.174.57 = INTEGER: 11
>   SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.104.181.153.172.54.237 = INTEGER: 11
>   SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.120.172.192.143.226.236 = INTEGER: 11
>   SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.124.195.161.20.109.76 = INTEGER: 11
>   SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.**152.75.225.59.127.180** = INTEGER: 11

Then you can do this to find which Mac Address is connected :

> $ snmpwalk -v 1 -c public xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1 |
>   grep "152.75.225.59.127.180"

Return mac address :

> SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.152.75.225.59.127.180 = Hex-STRING: **98
>   4B E1 3B 7F B4**

You can make a script.sh to do this...

Comment: In fact, the first query already contains the MAC address: "152.75.225.59.127.180" is the decimal representation of "98 4B E1 3B 7F B4". You don't need to do a second snmpwalk only to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there :) The dot1dTpFdbPort is exactly what are you looking for, the only thing that you need is a link to the real port index.

First, take the value given by dot1dTpFdbPort.

Now query the dot1dBasePortIfIndex with the value you took before.

Let's make an example:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c xxx 192.168.x.x 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1

SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.0.2.253.255.213.15 = Hex-STRING: XX XX XX XX XX XX

snmpwalk -v 2c -c xxx 192.168.x.x 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2

SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.0.2.253.255.213.15 = INTEGER: 22

# Notice the 22 :)

snmpwalk -v 2c -c xxx 192.168.x.x 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2.22

SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.1.4.1.2.22 = INTEGER: 10122
```

Comment: Let's note that this is not very efficient since you need to look at the whole table. Unfortunately, there doesn't seems to be a table that allows to perform a port -> MAC lookup directly.

Comment: @Marki, I don't think there could be such a thing, since there could be multiple MACs per port. It's a 1:N relationship, whereas MAC:port is 1:1. (Just went through this crap myself.)

Comment: Hence my remark that there could be a **table** (or tables, one per port) showing that relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to have the MAC address directly in HEX :

```
snmpwalk -OX -v 2c -c public xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Netsnmp's `snmptable` may be more readable here.

Example `dot1dTpFdb` table retrieval:

```
snmptable  -M +.  -m +ALL -v 2c -c public  -Ci  192.168.x.x    BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbTable
   index dot1dTpFdbAddress dot1dTpFdbPort dot1dTpFdbStatus
'..?...'   98:4B:E1:3B:7F:B4           13          learned
// other rows snipped for brevity
```

Example `dot1dBasePort` table retrieval:

```
snmptable  -M +.  -m +ALL -v 2c -c public  -Ci  192.168.x.x   BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBasePortTable
 index dot1dBasePort dot1dBasePortIfIndex    dot1dBasePortCircuit dot1dBasePortDelayExceededDiscards dot1dBasePortMtuExceededDiscards
    13            13                10113 SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                  0                                0
// other rows snipped for brevity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# This should iterate thru each active port. 
HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ## Change this to the ip address of the switch
echo
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public "$HOST" 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1 | grep "$" |awk -- '{print $4":"$5":"$6":"$7":"$8":"$9}'
```